# Android Proximity error

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, gimbal

After applying the proximity code that is posted on gimbal website, the following error is prompted "app is not initialized".
Knowing that the code had reached successfully to this command "Proximity.startService(this); "

I am using samsung note 3; android version 4.4.3.

Can somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the **Proximity.initialize()** method prior to calling the **Proximity.startService()** method. Look at the [Gimbal SDK documentation](http://gimbal.com/doc/) for details on what arguments you need to pass these methods.